# C# Nullable arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, nullable

I have a search function, but I would like `LocationID` to be an array of integers rather than just a single integer.   I'm not sure how to do this since I want it to also be nullable.  I've looked at doing `int?[]` but then I'd have to check the `HasValue` of every single entry.  Is there a better way?

This is what I currently have:

```
public ActionResult Search(string? SearchString, int? LocationId,
    DateTime? StartDate,  DateTime? EndDate)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Arrays are always reference types, as is `string` - so they're *already* nullable. You only need to use (and only *can* use) `Nullable<T>` where T is a non-nullable value type.

So you probably want:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchString, int[] locationIds,
                           DateTime? startDate,  DateTime? endDate)
```

Note that I've changed your parameter names to follow .NET naming conventions, and changed `LocationId` to `locationIds` to indicate that it's for multiple locations.

You might also want to consider changing the parameter type to `IList<int>` or even `IEnumerable<int>` to be more general, e.g.

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchString, IList<int> locationIds,
                           DateTime? startDate,  DateTime? endDate)
```

That way a caller could pass in a `List<int>` for example.

Answer (score 11):

Arrays are reference types, so you don't have to do anything, you already can pass `null`:

A method with the following signature can be called with all parameters as `null`:

```
public ActionResult Search(string SearchString, int[] LocationIds,
                           DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate)


foo.Search(null, null, null, null);
```

Please note: I additionally removed the question mark after `string` as it is a reference type as well.