# How to make int array Nullable?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code:

```
var contractsID = contracts.Select(x => x.Id);
int?[] contractsIDList = contractsID.ToArray();//for debug
```

In this line:

```
int?[] contractsIDList = contractsID.ToArray();//for debug
```

I get this error:

> Can not implicitly convert type int[] to int

what i try to do is to make contractsIDList  Nullable type.

How to make int array Nullable?

Comment: [C# Nullable arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069997/c-sharp-nullable-arrays)

Comment: Why do you want an array nullable? As a reference type it is already nullable.

Comment: I don't understand the error message. Is `x.Id` an `int?` or an `int`? Do you actually want to create a `int?[]` from an `int[]`?

Comment: Your error message doesn't make sense for the code you are showing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The error you *should* get is:

> Can not implicitly convert type int[] to int?[]

Thus you need to convert the values:

```
int?[] contractsIDList = contractsId.Cast<int?>().ToArray();//for debug
```

Comment: IMO, an ambiguous question has lead to a lot of disagreement.

Answer (score 10):

[Arrays are always reference types - so they're already nullable.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16070028/284240)

But i guess that you actually want to get an `int?[]` from an `int[]`(because the `Id` is not nullable). You can use `Array.ConvertAll`:

```
int[] contractsID = contracts.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
int?[] contractsIDList = Array.ConvertAll(contractsID, i => (int?)i);
```

or cast it directly in the LINQ query:

```
int?[] contractsIDList = contracts.Select(x => (int?) x.Id).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way in your case is to get `int?` from the `Select`:

```
var contractsID = contracts.Select(x => (int?)x.Id);
int?[] contractsIDList = contractsID.ToArray();
```

Comment: Could also be expressed as `contracts.Select(x => new int?(x.Id));`

Answer (score 1):

Use this One

```
int?[] contractsIDList = contractsID.ConvertAll<int?>((i) => { int? ni = i; return ni; }).ToArray();
```

Comment: I wondered if your 100% comment was true, it doesn't work at all. If `contractsID` is an array(what is it) you need to pass the array as parameter, it's not an instance method.

Comment: OP has showed his code: `var contractsID = contracts.Select(x => x.Id);`, it's an `IEnumerable<int>`.