# C#: int[] is nullable without declaring it so?

Tags: c#, integer, nullable, nullable-reference-types

I'm trying to use **ILGPU** to mess with **CUDA** on my **GPU**.

When I try to load a **kernel** and pass it some data:

```cs
var krnl = gpu.LoadAutoGroupedStreamKernel<Index1, ArrayView<byte>, int[]>(krnCopyStringToCard);
```

I get the following error, which is really confusing:

> The type 'int[]' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as a parameter...

Looking at **nullable** docs (new to me), it seems like `int` *can* be **nullable** but only if you declare it so. I'm definitely not doing that so what gives?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533757/is-int-a-reference-type-or-a-value-type , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/ , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113819/arrays-heap-and-stack-and-value-types

Comment: Do you want an explanation of the error, or do you want to fix the actual problem? If the later, you will need to supply the relevant code

Comment: I understand the error after the explanation. Unfortunately, unless you can help with the following problem, which is that I can't copy arrays (found a work-around by transferring 1 byte/int/etc. at a time--although that seems horribly ineffecient), I have all I need for now! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int` is non nullable, but `int[]` is, since

> [Array types are reference types.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/#array-overview)

---

You can see this on editor:

[image]

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069997/c-sharp-nullable-arrays/16070028#16070028) answer.